# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $ for Andoid

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am looking to call this api, but it seems to be in an object call.

> {"Abstract":"","AbstractSource":"Wikipedia","AbstractText":"","AbstractURL":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wire_characters","Answer":"","AnswerType":"","Definition":"","DefinitionSource":"","DefinitionURL":"","Entity":"","Heading":"The Wire characters","Image":"","ImageHeight":0,"ImageIsLogo":0,"ImageWidth":0,"Infobox":"","Redirect":"","RelatedTopics":[{"FirstURL":"https://duckduckgo.com/Alma_Gutierrez","Icon":{"Height":"","URL":"/i/8690ca01.jpg","Width":""},"Result":"<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/Alma_Gutierrez">Alma Gutierrez
> Alma M. Gutierrez is a fictional character on the HBO drama The Wire, played by actress Michelle Paress. Gutierrez is a dedicated and idealistic young reporter on the city desk of The Baltimore Sun.","Text":"Alma Gutierrez - Alma M. Gutierrez is a fictional character on the HBO drama The Wire, played by actress Michelle Paress. Gutierrez is a dedicated and idealistic young reporter on the city desk of The Baltimore Sun."},{"FirstURL":"https://duckduckgo.com/Augustus_Haynes","Icon":{"Height":"","URL":"/i/872d317a.jpg","Width":""},"Result":"<a href="https://duckduckgo.com/Augustus_Haynes">Augustus Haynes ...}

As you can see, the call is an object call, which is resulting to me having me get the error...

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $
```

How would you call the object instead of calling a list?

here's the Interface:

```
@Singleton
interface AnywhereAPI {
    @GET(".")
    suspend fun getAnyInfo(
        @Query("q") query : String = "the+wire+characters&format=json",
        @Query("format") format : String = "json"
    ): Response<List<GetAnyResponse>>
}
```

The repository:

```
class AnywhereRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: AnywhereAPI,
    private val anywhereDao: AnywhereDao
){
//  private val dataOrException = DataOrException<List<AnywhereListEntity>, Boolean, Exception>()
//
//    suspend fun getAllInfos(): DataOrException<List<AnywhereListEntity>, Boolean, Exception>{
//        try {
//            dataOrException.loading = true
//            dataOrException.data = api.getAnyInfo()
//        }
//    }

        val feeds: Flow<List<AnywhereListEntity>>
            get() = anywhereDao.getInfo()


    suspend fun anywhereInfo(): List<AnywhereListEntity>? {
        val request = api.getAnyInfo()
        if (request.isSuccessful){
            val anyItems = request.body()!!.map {
                AnywhereMapper.buildFrom(it)
            }
            anywhereDao.insertInfo(*anyItems.toTypedArray())
            return anyItems
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

the View Model:

```
class AnyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: AnywhereRepository
): ViewModel() {
   val anyInfoResults = repository.feeds

    init {
        getAnyList()
    }

    private fun getAnyList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
               repository.anywhereInfo()!!
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("REPO", e.message, e.cause)
        }

        }
    }
}
```

I'll leave a link to my project, so you guys can take a look at it. Thank you for the help
GitHub project
https://github.com/OEThe11/AnywhereCE

Also, the API URL: http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=the+wire+characters&format=json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse a List but you get a JSON object:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $
```

Try to change return type in Retrofit interface from `Response<List<GetAnyResponse>>` to `Response<GetAnyResponse>`.

Comment: I did try that. But since I am mapping certain values from the network data class to another data class, the map() function doesn't work.

Comment: If you want "map" values, you can try to replace `map` function to `let`. To fix the error from your post you must replace `Response<List<GetAnyResponse>>` to `Response<GetAnyResponse>`. And then fix other errors.

Comment: I corrected the errors and got an Error of "E/VM: Index: 0, Size: 0". I seems that the information didn't go into the database so that it can fill the data class.

Comment: If the initial error is fixed and you have a new error, please make a new question with a detailed error description and the stacktrace.